# Remove permissions lock on a Minecraft save

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I downloaded a pre-made Minecraft [save-file](http://www.minecraftsaves.net/map_459-hillside-manor.php) to explore, and it worked really well. However, when I tried using the `time set`, `gamemode`, or any other console command, I get the error `You do not have permission to use this command`.

So there is obviously some sort of permission lock in the save file that doesn't allow me to use console commands. How can I disable this lock and enable commands?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn cheats on or off](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277542/how-to-turn-cheats-on-or-off)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable cheats. You can either do this by using the Open to LAN menu, or an external NBT editor.